# R: Removing rows following a missing value in a sequence

Tags: r, sequence

I have different individuals that performed tests and were attributed a test number as to form a sequence that ranges from 0 to 3. For example:

```
ID            Nb_Test
A1            0
A1            1
A1            2
A2            1
A2            2
A2            3
A3            0
A3            1
A3            3
```

How could I remove tests of each individual that do not have a test #0 as well as tests that follow a break in the sequence. For example, I would like it to look like this:

```
ID            Nb_Test
A1            0
A1            1
A1            2
A3            0
A3            1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of possibilities, all relying on the same two logical checks: for a `0` `any`where in the group, and where the `diff`erence in the sequence is `1`.

Base R

```
dat[as.logical(ave(dat$Nb_Test, dat$ID, FUN=\(x) any(x==0) & c(TRUE, diff(x) == 1))),]
#  ID Nb_Test
#1 A1       0
#2 A1       1
#3 A1       2
#7 A3       0
#8 A3       1
```

*data.table*

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
dat[, if(any(Nb_Test==0)) .SD[c(TRUE, diff(Nb_Test) == 1)], by=ID]
#   ID Nb_Test
#1: A1       0
#2: A1       1
#3: A1       2
#4: A3       0
#5: A3       1
```

*dplyr*

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(any(Nb_Test == 0) & c(TRUE, diff(Nb_Test) == 1))
## A tibble: 5 x 2
## Groups:   ID [2]
#  ID    Nb_Test
#  <chr>   <int>
#1 A1          0
#2 A1          1
#3 A1          2
#4 A3          0
#5 A3          1
```